# Product-of-combinations and Combination-of-sums

Tags: combinatorics

Conjecture:

$\prod _{i=1}^N \binom{n_i}{r_i} < \binom{\sum_{i=1}^N n_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N r_i}$,

where $r_i,n_i$ are positive integers such that $\forall i, r_i \leq n_i$; and $\exists i, r_i < n_i $.

Is it true? If yes, is there any theorem and proof on it?

I have performed lots of experiments with random integers to generate the LHS and RHS and the result that no counterexamples have yet been found tend to support the conjecture.

Answer (score 3):

It is true indeed. Let's try to interpret the LHS and the RHS combinatorially.

LHS: You have N sets. Set $i$ has $n_i$ objects. You want to choose $r_i$ objects from the $i$th set. The LHS answers many ways can you do that.

RHS: Now imagine you grouped all the sets together. Now you have one set of $\sum n_i$ objects that you want to select $\sum r_i$ objects from.

Clearly, any selection while the objects are grouped into $N$ sets works as a selection when they're grouped together. The opposite is not true. When you group them together, you can select more than $r_i$ items from set $i$, and less from some other set to compensate. So LHS < RHS.

Comment: Thinking combinatorially is really powerful! My takeaway is that I should interpret objects combinatorially in the first place, instead of writing out the formulae explicitly as what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $0\le k_j\le n_j$ for all $1\le j\le m$,
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{n_1+n_2}{k_1+k_2}
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k_1+k_2}\binom{n_1}{j}\binom{n_2}{k_1+k_2-j}\tag1\\
&\ge\binom{n_1}{k_1}\binom{n_2}{k_2}\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: [Vandermonde Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)
$(2)$: one term ($j=k_1$) in a sum of non-negative numbers is no greater than the entire sum

Note that if $0\lt k_1+k_2\lt n_1+n_2$, there are at least two positive terms in $(1)$, so the inequality is strict.

Induction and $(2)$ show that
$$
\binom{\sum_{j=1}^mn_j}{\sum_{j=1}^mk_j}\ge\prod_{j=1}^m\binom{n_j}{k_j}\tag3
$$
and if $0\lt\sum_{j=1}^mk_j\lt\sum_{j=1}^mn_j$, the inequality in $(3)$ is strict.

Comment: This proof using Vandermonde's identity is beautiful. Furthermore, Step (2) also makes it clear to me why the RHS (in my question) is far greater than the LHS in a bunch of experiments.